# arbitrary value from checkbox causes hard time executing SQL statement on PDO

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, pdo

Sirs! I have a php script that handles multiple row update with PDO.
I want to add a checkbox that updates my database specific column by timestamp 30days from now if ticked.

<s>The problem is ofc, when it is not ticked, there would be no value sent to its key, so I would end up with:</s> It returns this error

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use...

So I'm asking for help if there's turn around for this, here is my PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `$tbl_name` SET `ssl`=:ssl, `exp`=:exp, `country`=:country, WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ssl', $ssl, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':exp', $exp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':country', $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    foreach ($_POST['ssl'] as $id => $ssl) {
        if(isset($_POST['thirtydays'][$id])){ 
            $exp = $_POST['thirtydays'][$id]; 
        }
        $country = $_POST['country'][$id];
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    echo '<h1>Updated the records.</h1>';
}
```

exp is the timestamp column. Here is the checkbox as HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="thirtydays[80]" value="2014-02-04 04:04:53"> 
<input type="text" name="country[80]" value="DE" />
<input type="text" name="ssl[80]" value="false"/>
```

Note the structure: `thirtydays[$id]`, the timestamp in value is generated by `date( "Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+30 days"))`

Hope somebody can help me. Thanks in advance and more power.

Comment: Missing first backtick to the left of `country` unless that's just a typo.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I updated, showing that the forms does really exist. The forms and PHP were working, before I put the checkbox.

Comment: I'm saying that in your query where it says `country=:country` you have a missing backtick. The first opening one.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh sorry, I over erased it. But still not working.

Comment: So you're saying that an error happens only if the field is left empty?

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry, you're right I ticked all the checkboxes, my analysis is wrong. It returns same error. help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$exp=''; $country=''; $ssl='';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `$tbl_name` SET `ssl`=:ssl, `exp`=:exp, `country`=:country WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ssl', $ssl, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':exp', $exp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':country', $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    foreach ($_POST['ssl'] as $id => $ssl) {
    if(isset($_POST['thirtydays'][$id])){ $exp = $_POST['thirtydays'][$id]; }
    $country = $_POST['country'][$id];
    $stmt->execute();
    }

    echo '<h1>Updated the records.</h1>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Query is executed only when checkbox is checked since `if (isset($_POST['thirtydays'][$id]))`
Also you set the `$exp` variable after you bind it to statement. 
Same goes to `$country` variable

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {  
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `$tbl_name` SET `ssl`=:ssl, `exp`=:exp, `country`=:country WHERE id=:id");  
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);  
    $stmt->bindParam(':ssl', $ssl, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    foreach ($_POST['ssl'] as $id => $ssl) {  
        if(isset($_POST['thirtydays'][$id])){   
            $exp = $_POST['thirtydays'][$id];  
        } else {  
            $exp = '';  
    }  
    $country = $_POST['country'][$id];  
    $stmt->bindParam(':exp', $exp, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    $stmt->bindParam(':country', $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    $stmt->execute();  
}  

echo '<h1>Updated the records.</h1>'; }
```

You have comma just before WHERE in your statement. This may be the problem.

Comment: Sir, the if statement is closed before $stmt->execute();

Comment: You're right, my mistake. Try to move `$stmt->bindParam(':exp', $exp, PDO::PARAM_STR);` and `$stmt->bindParam(':country', $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);` after defining `$exp` and `$country` variables in foreach loop

Comment: Yes, the comma is the problem, so the PDO error has stopped. Thank you very much about that, now about sending the values... Sir, we cannot empty $exp, it is either we update exp with new value or the value must retain its original. Sending empty would empty the original column, more like:

if(isset($_POST['thirtydays'][$id])){ $exp = $_POST['thirtydays'][$id]; } else {
// don't do anything
}

Answer (score 0):

To all who wonders (probably) what's *actually* wrong with the OP's code: inside the `` UPDATE `$tbl_name` SET `ssl`=:ssl, `exp`=:exp, `country`=:country, WHERE id=:id ``, the comma before `WHERE` is a syntax error. That's all.